# LISP downloading & parsing XML

Tags: xml, dom, lisp

I'm currently learning LISP and I have a quick question. Using CXML I can parse a local file easily enough, but I'm attempting to pull an XML file from the net and parse it in memory. I know there's something wrong with my code but I can't quite figure it out.

```
(cxml:parse-file (map 'string #'code-char
                   (drakma:http-request "http://api.eve-online.com/server/ServerStatus.xml.aspx"))
   (cxml-dom:make-dom-builder))
```

Comment: I've tried (cxml:parse-stream) and still no such luck. I have to map the results from the http-request due because drakma seems to return a byte array instead of strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
(cxml:parse (map 'string #'code-char (drakma:http-request "http://api.eve-online.com/server/ServerStatus.xml.aspx")) 
                                     (cxml-dom:make-dom-builder))
```

result:

```
#<RUNE-DOM::DOCUMENT {1005BECB53}>
```

`cxml:parse` is the command you're looking for if I understand correctly based on your example. `cxml:pars-stream` requires a stream, and `cxml:parse-file` requires a file... you're giving them neither, the argument you're passing to both of them is a string.

`cxml:parse-rod` is more specific and will parse only strings, while `cxml:parse` is generic and will parse files, streams, octets, and strings.

By the way, you can also do

```
(cxml:parse-octets (drakma:http-request "http://api.eve-online.com/server/ServerStatus.xml.aspx") (cxml-dom:make-dom-builder))
```

No need to convert the binary array from drakma to a string.